# In-App Purchase Titanium Android

Tags: android, titanium, in-app-billing

I am developing an **Android** Application using **Titanium Appcelerator** and now trying out **In-App purchase module** . But i don't have any google developer account yet.. Is it any way possible to get **Public key for sandbox testing** ??

Comment: I upvoted because I feel it is a legitimate question. Downvoters, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes and be less of a pill, k?

Answer (score 2):

You must have a google developer account (it is only $25) according [to this documentation, emphasis is my own:](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)

> No special account or registration is required *other than a Google Play Developer Console account and a Google Wallet merchant account*.

So in addition to your dev account, make sure you have the merchant account! Although the merchant account may not be necessary for actual [testing according to this document.](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) From what I gather, the main reason you need a dev account is to setup fake purchase items to test with.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly implied that you must have a Google Developer account to set up and test in-app purchase. You need to create the purchases in your Developer Console. Otherwise, when the module is making the requests to show the in-app dialog for purchasing something, there wouldn't be anything to show.

If you don't have access to an account yet, why don't you just show `alert("TODO: In app purchase!");` until you get one?